# Configuring IntelliJ IDEA to create main class for new projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, projects-and-solutions

A friend is just starting to learn Java, using IntelliJ.
He asks how can he set up some template so creating a new project will contain a default main class.

Currently, when he creates a new project, it has no source files, and he has to add a Run/Debug application configuration manually, and then select the main class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if Settings->File Templates is what you have in mind, but I'll point it out just in case.

You can easily create a class and add a main method by typing "psvm " and filling in the method body.  You run it by right clicking on the class and selecting "Run".  It's automatically be added to your Run/Config list, you just have to save it to make it permanent.

But my gut feeling is that IntelliJ has no such a feature for reading somebody's mind about a "default main class", nor should it.

Comment: Thanks, the first part of your answer helped, not sure what you meant in the last one.

Comment: if i'm writing a web app, what do i care about a main class that runs in a command shell?  your friend who's learning java and intellj, focusing on desktop stuff, is a special case.

Answer (score -3):

In the resources tree, right click on the class you want to be main and there should be item in the context menu like "Create main for xyz".

Comment: There is no such item in IntelliJ 14 or any other version that I've used back to 8.  Are you an IntelliJ user?